# Which mvn artifacts required for Axis2?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis

I'm trying to figure out which artifacts I must include in my pom.xml to get someone else's JAX-WS thin client to compile and run its junit tests.  As things currently stand, it compiles file using just the axis2-jaxws artifact:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

However, when I try to run my tests, I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.policy.Assertion
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:25)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.<init>(AxisConfiguration.java:85)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:767)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:113)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:90)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getClientConfigurationContext(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:92)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:219)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
```

I've tried switching the scope to "test" and even "compile" but made no difference.  Apparently, the Assertion class is not part of the jaxws dependency tree.  Some searching around on jarvana.com pointed me to the [ws-commons/policy artifact](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/ws-commons/policy/1.0/policy-1.0.jar!/org/apache/ws/policy/Assertion.class?classDetails=ok), but this is ancient.

I cannot seem to find an up-to-date artifact that goes with the latest jax-ws artifact.  I've tried including the [rampart-project artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.rampart/rampart-project/1.6.0) as well but to no avail.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Short search on Maven central (http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.ws.policy.Assertion%22) produced the same result. But why not using the ws-commons? or neethi which is used as a dependency in axis2-jaxws?

Comment: Well, neethi is already included as a dependency by maven, so it obviously doesn't include the right package.  The ws-commons artifact is so old that I am convinced there must be something newer to use.  Otherwise, I find myself including ws-commons for the Assertion exception, then need to include some other artifact for the next ClassNotFound exception, and it doesn't stop.  Which really makes no sense in my mind; I figured that there must be a list of artifacts required somewhere as opposed to me doing it trial-and-error.

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the stack trace which triggers this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn dependency:analize-only` which will tell you which artifacts are your coding referring but not declared

Comment: I believe that will only give me the dependencies that are used but aren't directly declared (ie: are declared via other dependencies), but won't actually tell me which classes/artifacts are completely missing.  Am I incorrect about this?